# Why does running my application create excess sessions and drop the database connection?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, oracle11g

I have created a database application using jsp/servlets that is now hosted in a production server. But when I do some tasks with the application, the number of database sessions goes to more than 150 then the connection is lost. If I don't restart the database server I cant work with the application. I am using ORACLE 11g.

Comment: What does "connection loss" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Is this an Oracle error?  An error from your application server?  Something else?  Are you measuring 150 connections by looking at the database's data dictionary (i.e. `v$session`)?  Or are you looking somewhere else?  Are the activities that you are doing a load test where you would expect to need 150 physical connections?  If not, you almost certainly have a connection leak in your code.

Comment: yes, i wanted to know how to handle the more processes which directed to the database, I found the error that was with my program, I haven't closed some database connections. Thanks Justin

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you can do two things,

1. you can exceed the number of processes which can handle by the database using the following command.

   ```
   alter system set sessions = 300 scope = spfile;
   ```

   To do this you have to login to the database as the system user.
2. You can check whether all the opened database connections are closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lack of proper database connection closes. When we do some repeated activities without closing database connections in each iteration. It increases the number of connections with the database and come to a maximum connections that can have according to the per-defined. To avoid this problem we can do two things,

1. we can increase the maximum session amount. And if you are increasing sessions parameter you should consider increasing processes and transactions parameter as well. Here is the formula you can use to determine their values.

> processes=x
>   sessions=x*1.1+5
>   transactions=sessions*1.1

To do this use the bellow sql scripts

> sql> alter system set processes=500 scope=both sid='*';
>
>   sql> alter system set sessions=555 scope=both sid='*';
>   sql> alter system set transactions=610 scope=both sid='*';

1. The other method is you can design your application to not exceed the database connections at one time more than the previously defined. Oracle automatically remove the  connections that is not using currently periodically. But this gets time.